# How do I get a GUI button to execute a function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on my game design final, and I need buttons that activate attacks when clicked. This is the first time we've flown solo so I'm pretty iffy with the Unity APIs.

Here is my current attempt:

```
    void OnGUI(){
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(100, 800, 50, 50), "A"))
        BladeStrike();  
}
    void BladeStrike(){
    if (STUN == 0) {
        float timeRemaining = 20f;
        }
}
```

This is all just getting a concept to work, the change on the float is just to see if the button click worked. Well, the button shows up just fine, the button clicks and: nothing happens at all.

STUN is set to 0 by default and there's no code implimented yet to potentially change it, and I've tried commenting it out, made no difference.

It just seems so simple, and that's why it's so frustrating!

Comment: Are you saying it never reaches the `float timeRemaining = 20f` line?  If it does, the _net effect_ is "nothing" anyway because you simply initialise a local variable and nothing more.  What was your expectation?

Comment: The timeRemaining variable is used elsewhere in the script as part of a timer, and would immediately set the timer back to 20s if invoked, just so I could see if the button worked. I shouldn't have the float in there like I'm creating it, I notice... well that's the first thing... edit: No, no, that's THE thing. It works now. Talking it out helped me realize the error. Thanks!

Comment: Use [Unity Tools for Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/unitytools-vs.aspx), place a break point in `BladeStrike()` and see if it stops in the debugger when you click the button in game.  Can't see why it won't

Comment: Yeah that's probably a better way to test. I tripped over my own two feet here!

Comment: Not a problem good sir.  Wishing you well

Answer (score 0):

I was presenting the variable as if I was creating it, when I was attempting to change an already existing variable instead. The solution is simply:

```
   void OnGUI(){
if (GUI.Button(new Rect(100, 800, 50, 50), "A"))
    BladeStrike();  
}
    void BladeStrike(){
if (STUN == 0) {
    timeRemaining = 20f;
    }
```

}